# searchDisplayController does not show searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the Calendar App, so far i have below code which when i click on the leftBarButton nothing than a small empty white space appears? why is there no searchBar in it?
What i want is when u click a new navigationBar appear with a searchBar

illustration when i click searchButton:

[image]

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //searchBar
    theSearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)
    theSearchBar?.delegate = self
    theSearchBar?.showsCancelButton = true
    theSearchBar?.placeholder = "Søg efter produkter"



    searchController = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: theSearchBar!, contentsController: self)
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsDelegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsDataSource = self




}


@IBAction func showSearchBar(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    theSearchBar?.becomeFirstResponder()
    searchController?.setActive(true, animated: true)



}
```

Comment: Maybe because: `UISearchBar(frame: CGRectZero)`? I'm not familiar with swift but just wanna help :)

Comment: Thank you for that, but it does not help :/

Comment: Well you can always use `UITableViewController` and put `UISearchBar` as the table header view? If you need help I can show you Objective-C code? :)

Comment: If you can go min iOS8 check out the new `UISearchController`

Comment: same issue here, I need iOS7 min